# Scheduled publish/unpublish strategy

Tags: publishing, publishing-service, scheduled-tasks

What is the recommended best approach to scheduled publish/unpublish strategy?

Ideally, I'd want to be able to make a page or rendering on a page to publish/unpublish at a specific date/time.

I believe I have to enable the scheduler in a config file, but I don't want to have the cache invalided every time this runs, and also don't want to cut content editors working on to publish before they're ready..

I am running `Sitecore 9`

Comment: When the content author is modifying a content which is already live, should the content get removed from the live site?

Answer (score 3):

We’ve used this module to great effect before and it is much more feature rich than the out of the box auto publishing task:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_Scheduled_Publish.aspx?sc_lang=en

It’s by the Hedgehog Guys, it’s also on GitHub here with docs:

https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/SCScheduledPublishing

I’ve not tried it with Sitecore 9 yet and it doesn’t say it works with 9 but it may well work, maybe install it on a dev instance and see.

The difference with this module is content editors get some nice new buttons in the ribbon next to publish where they can choose when to publish/unpublish their items:

[image]

It allows you to set a time and also supports versions which is nice:

[image]

They can see any other scheduled publish/unpublish too too:

[image]

From what I recall you can get it to send an email when something published too and control who can see the buttons too which is pretty nice.